# calling api with Ajax call

Tags: javascript

I try to call an external api resource.

The api recourse is from this link:
https://restcountries.com

And this is the javascript code:

```
const getCountry = function(country){ 

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-country");
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector(".countries");

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`);
request.send();

//console.log(request.responseText);

request.addEventListener("load", function () {
  //console.log(this.responseText);
  const [data] = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
 // console.log(data);

  const html = `
  <article class="country">
  <img class="country__img" src="${data.flags}" />
  <div class="country__data">
    <h3 class="country__name">${data.name}</h3>
    <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
    <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(
      +data.population / 1000000
    ).toFixed(1)} people</p>
    <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages}</p>
    <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies}</p>
  </div>
</article>
    `;
  countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
});
}


getCountry('portugal');
```

And this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script defer src="./restCountries.js"></script>
    <title>Asynchronous JavaScript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">
      <div class="countries">
      
      </div>
      <!-- <button class="btn-country">Where am I?</button> -->
      <div class="images"></div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I see that the data is returned in chrome tools.

But I still get this error:

```
[object%20Object]:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/jquery/Algorithms/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Comment: You need to use a string in ${country} property. Now it seems to be an object as you can see in the error messge.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I know you already solved your problem. But the error message `GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/jquery/Algorithms/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)` does not seem to match anything in your shown code. I mean the request URL there is `http://127.0.0.1:5500/jquery/Algorithms/` but the only URL you request in your code is  `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy. I am great.

So this works:

```
  request.open('GET', `https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`);
```

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: I somehow doubt that this was the only change you did in your code and that this change is really the reason for your code to work now. (See my other comment to your question)

Comment: I am sorry to tell you. But yes, this was the only change I made. And everything works now.